# MinGW compiler cannot be recognized in Clion

Tags: c++, mingw, clion

[image: This is what the error showed]`Clion` cannot compile `C++`, because it cannot find it.
I checked it many times and it was **exactly** where I installed `MinGW`.
I tried many ways online but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you can type `g++ --version` in a cmd.exe window and that works. If it does not perhaps your PATH environment variable does not have an entry for mingw or it is not properly set.

Comment: In the "Toolchains" settings you can explicitly set the paths to the compiler and other tools.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the correct path of my compiler but it is not recognizing it.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of the Toolchains setting, as well as a copy-paste of the CMake output?

Answer (score 0):

Add `MinGW` to the path of your operating System.